# How to do a multi query search in Lucene 7.4.0?

Tags: java, lucene, information-retrieval

I have two queries, one of them is boosted, and I want to combine them into one new query. I understand that in older version of Lucene you can do it with `BooleanQuery` using `add`. But in the version I'm using, that method seems to no longer exists. So how do I do it now?

Answer (score 0):

To add queries into a 'BooleanQuery', now I have to use the 'Builder'. So if I want to add queries, the code line should be something like `new BooleanQuery().Builder().add(query1).add(query2).build()`

Yes, I should've read the migration guide first.

Also  if I want to combine a boosted query and a normal one, I could just concate the strings.